# "The product doesn't exit" Error Magento 2 admin panel

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, grid, admin-panel, associate-products

"The product doesn't exist"  Error Magento 2 admin panel.

Thank you,
Your Faithfully,
Mehul Kanjariya

Following error show log file

> [2019-03-18 11:01:54] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entity_value.value' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `entity`.`sku`, `product_entity`.`entity_id` AS `product_id`, `attribute`.`attribute_code`, `entity_value`.`value` AS `value_index`, `attribute_label`.`value` AS `super_attribute_label`, IFNULL(option_value.value, default_option_value.value) AS `option_title`, `default_option_value`.`value` AS `default_title` FROM `catalog_product_super_attribute` AS `super_attribute`
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `product_entity` ON product_entity.entity_id = super_attribute.product_id
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `product_link` ON product_link.parent_id = super_attribute.product_id
>    INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS `attribute` ON attribute.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `entity` ON entity.entity_id = product_link.product_id
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `entity_value` ON entity_value.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id AND entity_value.store_id = 0 AND entity_value.entity_id = entity.entity_id
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute_label` AS `attribute_label` ON super_attribute.product_super_attribute_id = attribute_label.product_super_attribute_id AND attribute_label.store_id = 0
>    LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option` AS `attribute_option` ON attribute_option.option_id = entity_value.value
>    LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `option_value` ON option_value.option_id = entity_value.value AND option_value.store_id = 0
>    LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `default_option_value` ON default_option_value.option_id = entity_value.value AND default_option_value.store_id = 0 WHERE (super_attribute.product_id = 31659) AND (attribute.attribute_id = '') ORDER BY `attribute_option`.`sort_order` ASC
>    {"exception":"[object] (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entity_value.value' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `entity`.`sku`, `product_entity`.`entity_id` AS `product_id`, `attribute`.`attribute_code`, `entity_value`.`value` AS `value_index`, `attribute_label`.`value` AS `super_attribute_label`, IFNULL(option_value.value, default_option_value.value) AS `option_title`, `default_option_value`.`value` AS `default_title` FROM `catalog_product_super_attribute` AS `super_attribute`
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `product_entity` ON product_entity.entity_id = super_attribute.product_id
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `product_link` ON product_link.parent_id = super_attribute.product_id
>    INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS `attribute` ON attribute.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `entity` ON entity.entity_id = product_link.product_id
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `entity_value` ON entity_value.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id AND entity_value.store_id = 0 AND entity_value.entity_id = entity.entity_id
>    LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute_label` AS `attribute_label` ON super_attribute.product_super_attribute_id = attribute_label.product_super_attribute_id AND attribute_label.store_id = 0
>    LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option` AS `attribute_option` ON attribute_option.option_id = entity_value.value
>    LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `option_value` ON option_value.option_id = entity_value.value AND option_value.store_id = 0
>    LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `default_option_value` ON default_option_value.option_id = entity_value.value AND default_option_value.store_id = 0 WHERE (super_attribute.product_id = 31659) AND (attribute.attribute_id = '') ORDER BY `attribute_option`.`sort_order` ASC
>    at /home/domains/dev.test.com/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entity_value.value' in 'field list' at /home/domains/dev.test.com/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"} []

[image]

Comment: did you check exception.log?

Comment: hello friend  i have log add to my question please help me

Comment: This might help you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242004/magento-2-reindex-fail-unknown-column-entity-value-value-in-field-list

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I have the same problem in my website

Answer (score 0):

This same happens to me when i downgraded magento to 2.3.3 from 2.3.4.

For this I just run below query in phpmyadmin

```
DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE 'custom_layout_update_file'
```

after that I run upgrade and reindex command and everything working fine now.

Hope this will help you and others