# Magento 2 Error click on admin grid edit

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, grid, admin-panel, simple-product

Magento2 error  when clicking edit configurable product

below error shown

> 2 exception(s): Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception):
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'entity_value.value' in 'field list', query was: SELECT
>   `entity`.`sku`, `product_entity`.`entity_id` AS `product_id`,
>   `attribute`.`attribute_code`, `entity_value`.`value` AS `value_index`,
>   `attribute_label`.`value` AS `super_attribute_label`,
>   IFNULL(option_value.value, default_option_value.value) AS
>   `option_title`, `default_option_value`.`value` AS `default_title` FROM
>   `catalog_product_super_attribute` AS `super_attribute`  INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_product_entity` AS `product_entity` ON
>   product_entity.entity_id = super_attribute.product_id  INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_product_super_link` AS `product_link` ON
>   product_link.parent_id = super_attribute.product_id  INNER JOIN
>   `eav_attribute` AS `attribute` ON attribute.attribute_id =
>   super_attribute.attribute_id  INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS
>   `entity` ON entity.entity_id = product_link.product_id  INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_product_entity` AS `entity_value` ON
>   entity_value.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id AND
>   entity_value.store_id = 0 AND entity_value.entity_id =
>   entity.entity_id  LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute_label` AS
>   `attribute_label` ON super_attribute.product_super_attribute_id =
>   attribute_label.product_super_attribute_id AND
>   attribute_label.store_id = 0  LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option` AS
>   `attribute_option` ON attribute_option.option_id = entity_value.value 
>   LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `option_value` ON
>   option_value.option_id = entity_value.value AND option_value.store_id
>   = 1  LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `default_option_value` ON default_option_value.option_id = entity_value.value AND
>   default_option_value.store_id = 0  INNER JOIN
>   `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock` ON stock.product_id =
>   entity.entity_id WHERE (super_attribute.product_id = 24079) AND
>   (attribute.attribute_id = '') AND (stock.stock_status = 1) ORDER BY
>   `attribute_option`.`sort_order` ASC
>
> Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054
>   Unknown column 'entity_value.value' in 'field list'

So help me, someone.
Thank You

Comment: Have you added anything custom here?

Comment: No i cannot add custom

Comment: Check this link you can help for same.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242004/magento-2-reindex-fail-unknown-column-entity-value-value-in-field-list